# MPEG4 videos cannot be played on iOS14 (AVPlayer issue)

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, h.264, ios14, mpeg

I have a piece of code that uses ffmpeg with default mpeg4 codec to merge multiple videos and audio songs.

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex "concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" -f MOV -vn -y output.mp4
```

Everything worked on iOS13 and after the update to iOS14, videos are black and cannot be played by any player. Sound is there and it's good.
I tried to switch to h264 and it works good, but as you already know, h264 is under GPL and it is expensive and requires code to be open sourced which is not acceptable for me.

None of the mpeg4 videos can be played in AVPlayer.

What was changed? Anything in release notes?
Is that a bug? Or a feature?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure iOS 14 supports MPEG-4 Part 2 videos? Are all MPEG-4 Part 2 videos (assuming that is what your output is) not playable in iOS 14, or just the ones created by ffmpeg? Show the complete log from your command.

Comment: h264 is not GPL. x264 is, but that is not the same thing as h264.

Comment: @szatmary Ok, but package that has h264 is x264 in ffmpeg library and it's under GPL. How to use h264 if not by using x264 ? Thanks for helping out

Comment: There are other encoders, including open264. But you are confusing code license with patent realities. They are completely separate things.

Comment: @vanste25, have you resolved this issue? I’m having the same problem playing MPEG-4 in iOS14. I am hoping if you have some advice.

Comment: @Fernand  I haven't.. We switched to native encoding in iOS so it's good. But encoding with FFMPEG and mpeg4 does not work still

Comment: @vanste25, that's too bad. Thank you for letting me know.